# Mutual Information for feature selection text classification

Tags: text, text-classification

I use Naive Bayesian classifier for text classification. How can I make improvements of the accuracy of the algorithm using Mutual information measure for feature selection?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 improvements that you can use in text classification . First , you improve using the preprocessing techniques that you use such as N-Gram. Second, you can use feature selection techniques such as TF-IDF, Mutual Information, Chi-Square, and use other optimizations algorithm such as Genetic Algorithm, Bat Algorithm, ABC-Colony, Ant Colony. TF-IDF is very popular in information retrieval. Naive bayes is very sensitive with feature selection method.So, you can combine preprocessing techniques, feature selection method, and classification method for optimizing the classification result.